# OpenMP set fixed size of chunks based on a runtime param

Tags: c, openmp

Let's say I have a vector of n elements and n_threads available.
I want to use `#pragma omp parallel` such that each thread receives n / n_threads chunk size,
and the last one more depending on the case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{

    int *v = malloc ( n * sizeof(int) );

    #pragma omp parallel for (what should i put here?)
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        ++v[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ex: n = 10003, n_threads = 4

- thread_0 should get 2500 chunks
- thread_1 should get 2500 chunks
- thread_2 should get 2500 chunks
- thread_3 should get 2503 chunks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - you can't do that. All you can do is to specify the `schedule(static)` clause without specifying the chunk size and the OpenMP runtime will divide the iterations count in approximately the same sized chunks. How exactly will it be done is up to the implementation. This is what the OpenMP standard says about static scheduling:

> When schedule(static, chunk_size) is specified, iterations are divided into chunks of size chunk_size, and the chunks are assigned to the threads in the team in a round-robin fashion in the order of the thread number.
> When no chunk_size is specified, the iteration space is divided into chunks that are approximately equal in size, and at most one chunk is distributed to each thread. Note that the size of the chunks is unspecified in this case.

For n = 10003 and n_threads = 4, you can specify chunk size of 2500 and the iteration space will be divied into chunks of size 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500 and 3 and they will be distributed to threads 0, 1, 2, 3 and 0. Thus thread 0 will get 2503 iterations but they will not be contiguous in the iteration space. If you do not specify the chunk size, it is up to the implementation to decide which thread to give the extra iterations to.

Comment: I only know the vector size at runtime(implicitly the chunk_size too). I was trying to avoid using pthreads, but it seems I can't use openmp to do what I need right now.

Comment: Here is an example of how the GNU OpenMP runtime schedules 103 iterations with `schedule(static)` between 4 threads on Mac OS X: thread 0 - 26 iterations, thread 1 - 26 iterations, thread 2 - 26 iterations, thread 3 - 25 iterations. All iterations are contiguous.

Comment: @DanLincan You can still use OpenMP, you'll just have to calculate the begin and end indices of the chunks yourself. Can be done by a few lines protected by `#pragma omp critical { /* calculate next chunk indices */ }` Still much shorter than with pthreads. There may even be a better way to do this with OpenMP. I'm not an expert...

Comment: Much better: use `omp_set_schedule()`. See my answer for details.

Comment: @jcsahnwaldt what do you need the critical section for? Computing the iteration bounds for each thread does not modify any shared variables in the static scheduling case.

Comment: @HristoIliev You're right. I initally had another idea for calculating chunks dynamically that required accessing a shared variable. See [the first version of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53073735/1). I later realized it didn't really do what Dan Lincan wanted. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, OpenMP doesn't guarantee exact chunk sizes, but it's not too hard to calculate them yourself. Here's some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(void) {

  int n = 10003;
  int n_threads = 4;
  int chunk_size = n / n_threads;

  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(n_threads)
  {
    int id = omp_get_thread_num();
    int b = id * chunk_size;
    int e = id == n_threads - 1 ? n : b + chunk_size;
    printf("thread %d: %d items\n", id, e - b);
    for (int i = b; i < e; i++) {
      // process item i
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
thread 0: 2500 items
thread 1: 2500 items
thread 3: 2503 items
thread 2: 2500 items
```

**Beware:** The strategy "each thread gets n / n_threads items, the last one more" is fine for the numbers you gave, but it may lead to very inefficient work sharing in other cases. For example, with 60 items and 16 threads, this formula would give all threads 3 items - except the last one, which would get 15 items. If processing each item takes roughly the same time, this would mean that the whole process takes about four times longer than necessary, and most CPU cores would be idle most of the time. I think you should only use this formula if there are good reasons why you need to distribute the work in exactly this way. Otherwise, the chunk sizes chosen by OpenMP are probably better.

Comment: Why would you both mess with the number of threads and with the runtime schedule type when a simple `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(num_threads) schedule(dynamic, chunk_size)` does the same?

Comment: You're totally right. I thought the OpenMP pragmas could only take compile-time values, but I was wrong. Anyway, the initial version of my answer was closer to a solution for the original problem. I'll revert. Thanks for the comment!